# Using diag() in R

Tags: r, matlab, matrix

I am looking at this piece of code which I am translating to Matlab, I only have the source code not a running version in R.

```
Result[,1:2]<-diag(max)
```

Where max is a [2*1] array.

I had assumed that this was creating a diagonal matrix on the rhs which is assigned to the first 4 elements in Result.

However, I now think that only the diagonal elements on the lhs should be changes (to the max values from the RHS). Is this the correct reading of the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will not assign. Just compare matrix , elements by elements.
It works only if you have the correct dimensions.
Here an example:

```
set.seed(1234)

Result <- matrix(rnorm(20),nrow=2)
Result[,1:2] <= diag(max(c(2,2)))

     [,1]  [,2]
[1,]  TRUE FALSE
[2,] FALSE  TRUE
```

Here an example where you get error( the most probable case)

```
Result[,1:2] <= diag(max(c(2,4)))
Error in Result[, 1:2] <= diag(max(c(2, 4))) : non-conformable arrays
```

**EDIT** after OP edit

If the original code is

```
Result[,1:2] <- diag(max(c(2,2)))

   [,1] [,2]      [,3]       [,4]       [,5]
[1,]    1    0 0.4291247 -0.5747400 -0.5644520
[2,]    0    1 0.5060559 -0.5466319 -0.8900378
```

The code will assign a diagonal matrix (4th elemntss) as shwon a bove, but this will not work if you don't have the right dimension. Fo example:

```
  Result <- matrix(rnorm(6),nrow=3)
  Result[,1:2] <- diag(max(c(2,2)))

 Error in Result[, 1:2] <- diag(max(c(2, 2))) : 
 number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

You have an error because results have more rows than RHS.

```
Result
           [,1]       [,2]
[1,] -1.2070657 -2.3456977
[2,]  0.2774292  0.4291247
[3,]  1.0844412  0.5060559
```

and RHS is

```
diag(max(c(2,2)))
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    0
[2,]    0    1
```

Comment: Sorry the original code should be Result[,1:2]<-diag(max) not Result[,1:2]<=diag(max)!! The code should certainly be assigning values from right to left not comparing.

Comment: thanks again, I am getting results (in Matlab) like your first example. I.e. a diagonal matrix in the first four elements. However this seems to be incorrect for the overall logic of the model. I think the offdiagnal elements should NOT be set to zero, they should remain unchaged from what they originally were on the LHS. What would this look like in R code and is possible MATLAB code?

Comment: in R you can do this `Result[row(Result)==col(Result)] <- max(c(1,2))`